# MockMVC jUnit Spring test

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockmvc

I need help with the jUnit testing, my result is json file, and I need to test the length of that file, the problem is there is no such method inside the jsonPath function.

```
@Test
@Transactional
    public void getMunicipalitiesByCity() throws Exception {

        restSampleMockMvc.perform(get("/api/insurancePlan/municipalities/city/{cityName}", "esc"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.length").value(7));
```

Here is my test method the expected length is 7. 
any help would be appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using hamcrest matcher:

```
.andExpect((jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(7))));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.
For the record its org.hamcrest.Matchers